# BioMart Ensembl id imperfect retrieval

Tags: r, biomart

I have a list of gene symbols:

```
c("cd45", "Tmem119", "CD11b", "P2Yr12", "Csf1r", "Bst2", "Cd74", 
"Cx3cr1", "Trem2", "Lyz2", "GLAST", "GFAP", "ALDH1L1", "Aldoc", "Aqp4", 
"Glul", "S100a", "Olig1", "Olig2", "Olig3", "Mbp", "Pdgfra", "Pecam", 
"Cldn5", "Cldn10", "Epas1", "Crip1")
```

If I feed it to `BioMart` to get `ensembl ids`:

```
mart <- useDataset("mmusculus_gene_ensembl", useMart("ensembl"))
list <- getBM(filters= "mgi_symbol", attributes= c("ensembl_gene_id",
                           "mgi_symbol","description"),values=symbols,mart= mart)
```

the following genes are missed:

```
"cd45"   "cd11b"  "p2yr12" "glast"  "s100a"  "pecam"
```

All of them are pretty well-known genes, and I can manually find their `ensembl ids` by googling it, for instance:

http://www.informatics.jax.org/marker/MGI:97810

I tried supplying aliases, but it does not change the output. So, from my understanding `BioMart` is not working properly either because I am doing something wrong here or because `BioMart` itself is not a good tool to use. Is there a better way of getting the mapping that would map all of the gene symbols?

Answer (score 4):

The genes that are missed are probably not official mgi symbols.

You might wanna look them up at mgi:

```
cd45 -> Ptprc 

cd11b -> Itgam 

p2ry12 -> P2ry12 (?) (CAPS sensitive?)    

glast -> Slc1a3 

s100a -> S100a1 

pecam -> Pecam1 (?)
```

I suspect biomaRt is not the problem here, the only better way I can come up with is to download the ENSEMBL annotation (GTF) [file](ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-92/gtf/mus_musculus), and get the symbol out of this annotation with AWK or in R.

Here an example in R, since you don't want to use AWK:

```
file <- read.table("Mus_musculus.GRCm38.78.gtf", sep = "\t", comment.char = "#")

exons <- subset(file, V3 == 'exon')

V9 <- file[,"V9"]

ensembl_names <- sub("gene_id ","",V9)

split <- strsplit(ensembl_names, ";")

splitting <- sapply(split, function(x) x[1])

split_symbol <- strsplit(ensembl_names, "gene_name ")

splitting_symbol <- sapply(split_symbol, function(x) x[2])

splitting_symbol2 <- strsplit(splitting_symbol, "; ")

symbol_names <- sapply(splitting_symbol2, function(x) x[1])

ensemble_symbol_big <- cbind(splitting, symbol_names)

ensembl_symbol <- unique(ensemble_symbol_big)

colnames(ensembl_symbol) <- c("ENSEMBL", "Symbol")

write.table(ensembl_symbol, "ensembl_symbol.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = F)
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by look up at `mgi`. I tried supplying `mgi` instead of `mgi_symbol`, and it did not work. Not sure whether it is an issue with `biomart` or not. How to do that with `AWK`? Can you give any links for doing that, tutorials? To learn whole new language just to do translation of `ensembl ids` to `symbols` seems like an overkill a bit, if it is not very easy.

Comment: What I mean with "look up at mgi", is look up the genes that are missed: e.g., [cd45](http://www.informatics.jax.org/marker/MGI:97810), and [cd11b](http://www.informatics.jax.org/marker/MGI:96607). You'll see that your names do not match the name given after **Symbol**, so how do you expect biomaRt to recognize them? I think `AWK` is a great tool for bioinformaticians, but if you don't want to make use of this tool, don't. I do not want to force you into something.